# sudo apt-get install npm not getting installed

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

I tried running `sudo apt-get install npm` it returns me this dialogue below. How can I resolve the issue?

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be 
installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I think `npm` can only be installed when we have already installed `node`. Try installing that `node-gyp` first.

Comment: @samAlvin node-gyp needs npm to install. 'npm install -g node-gyp-install'

Answer (score 7):

npm gets installed along with nodejs. If you have node installed, you have npm as well.

run `node -v` to check if node is installed, then run `npm -v` to do the same for npm.

If nodejs is not installed, check installation instructions here:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

6.x is the current stable branch.

In general, to run a wipe existing node/npm installation and install from scratch, run:

```
sudo apt remove --purge nodejs node npm
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: followed the steps still the same issue when i try installing npm. Even curl is not installed and get similar error The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    curl : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.47.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: What happens if you run `npm install npm@latest -g`?

Comment: The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install npm

Comment: Also, check run `sudo apt install build-essential` to make sure it's installed and apparently you also need gnutls, run`sudo apt install libgnutls-dev` and try again. If everything fails, the safest thing would be to completely remove node and reinstall it, it should install npm properly as well.

Comment: Running the sudo apt install libgnutls-dev gives me this: 
 libgnutls-dev : Depends: libgnutls30 (= 3.4.10-4ubuntu1) but 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.3 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgnutls-openssl27 (= 3.4.10-4ubuntu1) but 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.3 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgnutlsxx28 (= 3.4.10-4ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: nettle-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libtasn1-6-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libp11-kit-dev but it is not going to be installed

Comment: completely removed nodejs  and tried reinstalling still get the same issue.

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f` to try and fix broken dependencies

Comment: You're welcome, too bad it didn't help, since I've run out of ideas :/. There might be a dependency issue caused by some other installation or package removal, which is difficult to track.

Comment: I have installed npm alongside node. Using `npm -v` I get 5.6.0, but when I use `sudo npm install <package>`, I get the error, >>> sudo: npm: command not found. I tried using `su` but then I got `The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install npm`. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to make sure that npm is included in your PATH environment variable. Run `echo $PATH` and make sure that the output contains `:/usr/bin:`, or the directory where you have installed node with npm.

Answer (score 3):

The best and easiest way to install node and npm is by nvm(node version manager).

1. Run the below code to install nvm

   `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash`

2.Then run

```
nvm install node
```

npm will be installed alongside node

This method will be the easiest and safest way for npm and node installation.

For installing a specific node and npm you can do it like below:

```
nvm install v6.11.3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey not able to install curl, i get something like The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.47.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: You have dependency problems in your Ubuntu you need to install those dependencies using the following command                                                                     (apt-get -y build-dep libcurl3-gnutls-dev)   and then follow with  the command  (apt-get -y install libcurl3-gnutls-dev)

Comment: How is this easier than `apt-get install npm`?

Comment: It is easier when you want to install multiple node instances in one computer. Managing them at that time is a hassle, and `nvm` is a better alternative